# How to group records when grouping should be skipped in a discontinued range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Products
    (Product VARCHAR(100), BeginDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME NULL, Rate INT);

INSERT INTO #Products (Product, BeginDate, EndDate, Rate)
VALUES ('Football', '01-01-1982', '05-03-2011', 2),
    ('Football', '05-04-2011', '08-01-2012', 1),
    ('Football', '08-02-2012', '01-01-2013', 2),
    ('Football', '01-02-2013', NULL, 3),
    ('Eggs', '01-01-1982', '05-03-2011', 1),
    ('Eggs', '05-04-2011', '08-01-2012', 1),
    ('Eggs', '08-02-2012', NULL, 1),
    ('Potato', '01-01-1982', '05-03-2011', 1),
    ('Potato', '05-04-2011', '08-01-2012', 1),
    ('Potato', '08-02-2012', '08-01-2013', 2),
    ('Potato', '08-02-2013', '08-01-2014', 2),
    ('Potato', '08-02-2014', '08-01-2015', 3),
    ('Potato', '08-02-2015', NULL, 3);
```

Expected result:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results
    (Product VARCHAR(100), BeginDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME NULL, Rate INT);

INSERT INTO #Results (Product, BeginDate, EndDate, Rate)
VALUES ('Football', '01-01-1982', '05-03-2011', 2),
    ('Football', '05-04-2011', '08-01-2012', 1),
    ('Football', '08-02-2012', '01-01-2013', 2),
    ('Football', '01-02-2013', NULL, 3),
    ('Eggs', '01-01-1982', NULL, 1),
    ('Potato', '01-01-1982', '08-01-2012', 1),
    ('Potato', '08-02-2012', '08-01-2014', 2),
    ('Potato', '08-02-2014', NULL, 3);
```

I want to group by `product` and `rate` column, but skip grouping if rate change isn't continuous. for instance the case of `football` in the given test data. In case of `football` although there are two rows with `Rate` of 2, it shouldn't be `grouped` because there was a different rate for a time period. The `BeginDate` value will always be 1 day ahead of previous `EndDate`.

I tried `group by` but that didn't work.

Comment: Your expected results is a create table statement?

Comment: No. Its a temp table loaded with expected result.

Comment: Group By would't work in this case. What you want to do is to begin to compare dates to see if there's a break first and then grab the Product and Rate. It's the comparison of dates that you will need to logically code. Because you can have multiple rows that may or may not overlap. You will need to read each Begin and End date of each row and then compare them per Rate, Product.  Here is a documentation: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/calculating-gaps-between-overlapping-time-intervals-in-sql/

Comment: Last row in the sample result shown should be `('Potato', '08-02-2014', NULL, 3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an islands problem, one possible solution

```
SELECT Product, min(BeginDate), EndDate, rate
FROM (
   SELECT Product, BeginDate, rate
      ,last_value(EndDate) over(partition by Product, Rate order by BeginDate 
                                 rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) EndDate
      ,row_number() over(partition by Product order by BeginDate) - row_number() over(partition by Product, Rate order by BeginDate) grp
    FROM #Products
    ) t
GROUP BY Product, grp, EndDate, rate
ORDER BY Product, min(BeginDate)
```

Result

```
Product (No column name)    EndDate rate

Eggs    01.01.1982 00:00:00 NULL    1
Football    01.01.1982 00:00:00 01.01.2013 00:00:00 2
Football    04.05.2011 00:00:00 01.08.2012 00:00:00 1
Football    02.08.2012 00:00:00 01.01.2013 00:00:00 2
Football    02.01.2013 00:00:00 NULL    3
Potato  01.01.1982 00:00:00 01.08.2012 00:00:00 1
Potato  02.08.2012 00:00:00 01.08.2014 00:00:00 2
Potato  02.08.2014 00:00:00 NULL    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` to get the previous row's endDate and Rate and use a `case` expression to start a new group when the specified conditions aren't met. Use `sum() over()` to assign groups. Thereafter, you can use `first_value` window function to get the first beginDate, last endDate and the rate per product,group.

```
select distinct product,
first_value(begindate) over(partition by product,grp order by beginDate),
first_value(enddate) over(partition by product,grp order by beginDate desc),
max(rate) over(partition by product,grp)
from
  (select p.*,
          sum(case when datediff(day,prevEnd,beginDate)=1 and prevRate=Rate then 0 else 1 end) 
          over(partition by product order by beginDate) as grp
   from
     (select p.*,
      lag(endDate,1,endDate) over(partition by product order by beginDate) as prevEnd,
      lag(Rate,1,Rate) over(partition by product order by beginDate) as prevRate
      from #Products p
     ) p 
  ) p
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/MDYNH75726)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row_Number and query as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from (
    SElect *, RowN = Row_number() over (partition by Product order by begindate) - Row_number() over (partition by product,rate order by begindate)
    from #Products
) a order by row_number() over(partition by Product, Rate, RowN order by BeginDate)
```

Comment: Thank-you Kannan, but this doesn't return the expected outcome. The BeginDate and EndDate don't match for Potato and Eggs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it

```
 select * 
   from ( select * 
               , lag(Rate, 1) over(partition by product order by beginDate) as prevRate 
               , lag(Product, 1) over(partition by product order by beginDate) as prevProduct
            from #Products 
        ) lag   
  where ( rate <> prevRate or prevRate is null ) and product = isnull(prevProduct, product)
  order by Product, BeginDate
```

Comment: Paparazzi, thank-you for the answer, but the EndDate on potato is not as expected.

Comment: It satisfies the stated rules.  Answer is only as good as the question.  Did you make any effort to fix correct?

Comment: I was going through all the answers I received and am still trying to grasp the concept how the ones that had same result as I wanted had solved it. Yours had result different than I was trying to get, so thought you might want to know. Anyway, thank-you for that question remark, it's very encouraging!

Comment: TSQL is arbitrary if not given specific instructions